# i have problem to install tomcat in ubuntu 18.4

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

when i wanna change owner of the directory :
`base) merat@HP-Pavilion:/opt/tomcat$ sudo chgrp –R tomcat /opt/tomcat`
i got this‌:
**chgrp: invalid group: ‘–R’**
i added tomcat group and user befor but when i run this : `(base) merat@HP-Pavilion:/opt/tomcat$ id tomcat` i got **id: ‘tomcat’: no such user**
also for group :
`(base) merat@HP-Pavilion:/opt/tomcat$ groups tomcat`
i got **groups: ‘tomcat’: no such user**
when i add it again :
`(base) merat@HP-Pavilion:/opt/tomcat$ sudo groupadd tomcat`
i got : **groupadd: group 'tomcat' already exists**
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> groups shows you your groups and not all. You could list all groups
>   for example like that:
>
> ```
> getent group
> ```
>
> If you added yourself to the group, you'll need to logout and login
>   for the change to take effect.

taken from [groupadd-group-xxxx-already-exist ASK UBUNTU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/670140/groupadd-group-xxxx-already-exist)